# Copy node tree from one material to another in cycles using python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have two cycles materials (say source and target). I want to copy the Shader Nodetree from the source material to the target material after clearing any currently present node tree(s) in the target material all in python.

Comment: Another way is to copy the object itself to another file. And apply the material that is copied together with that object to the other object :)

Comment: Yeah that seems a lot of work. So I just scripted the whole node setup and used it whenever I needed it. Thanks for the help.